# How do I strip out everything from an address except street name?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to return the street name from an address that is a string of text.

So from this:
`401 Buttercup Creek Blvd #1006`

I want to return 
`Buttercup Creek`

Removing the number is rather easy.

```
=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(<address>," ")),not(isnumber(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(<address>," ")))))
```

How would I write an expression that then filters out a list of words I define? Suppose I build a table with the following values:

- #
- Blvd
- Blvd.
- Boulevard
- ...

Or is there a way to do with a regex or something like that?

If I wasn't dealing with an array, I could search that table using this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(<RefTable>,<cell with text>)))>0
```

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet that shows the structure of your data and the desired output please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\d+|Blvd|#|Ave", ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That works well and is elegant in its simplicity. Is there a way to build that regular expression with a reference to a table versus hardcoding into the formula?

Comment: sure, if your exclusion values are in D column then: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|",1,D:D), ))))`

Comment: That is so cool! I modified that slightly to include the `\d+`. So the final was ```=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(<addresses>, TEXTJOIN("|",true,"\d+",<references>), ))))```